# WordPress Theme customisation CSS

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

I am building a WordPress theme. Which allows user to modify more than a hundred CSS properties. Now I can't decide how to apply the custom CSS.

Currently I have some custom CSS inserted into `wp-head` and some are applied using a `LESS` file, like this :

```
less.modifyVars({
            '@color': '<?php echo $this->sanitize_hex_color_front( WPEdenThemeEngine::NextGetOption( 'color_scheme', '#2C3E50' ) ); ?>',
            '@acolor': '<?php echo $this->sanitize_hex_color_front( WPEdenThemeEngine::NextGetOption( 'a_color', '#2C3E50' ) ); ?>',
            '@ahcolor': '<?php echo $this->sanitize_hex_color_front( WPEdenThemeEngine::NextGetOption( 'ah_color', '#2C3E50' ) ); ?>',

        });
```

Which also is inserted into `wp-head` as a `js` object.
Then use this variables for different css selector inside the `less` file.

I want to use one of these ways to apply the custom CSS or any other way, whichever leads to faster theme load time.

Comment: This doesn't sound specific to WordPress. If you want to focus on performance then you should be _measuring_ performance of your implementation. It is hard to guess what would work best for your case.

Comment: theme load time depends on the quality of the code, it is rarely related to some "trick" being used

Answer (score 2):

I'll describe what I did on a project recently that had similar requirements.

First thing I did was bundle [less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php) in my theme and create a function to compile a .less file in my theme into CSS and return the result. It looked like this:

```
function wpse_283711_get_customizer_css() {
    $css = '';

    if ( file_exists( get_theme_file_path( 'customizer.less' ) ) ) {
        require_once get_parent_theme_file_path( '/lib/less.php/Less.php' );

        $less = new Less_Parser;

        $less->parseFile( get_theme_file_path( 'customizer.less' ) );

        $less->ModifyVars( array(
            'primaryColor' => get_theme_mod( 'primary_color' ),
        ) );

        $css = $less->getCss();
    }

    return $css;
}
```

In my theme I have `customizer.less` which includes all the selectors and rules that I want to customize, with `@` less variables for where I want my custom values. For the above example, it might look like:

```
body {
    color: @primaryColor;
}
```

In this function `ModifyVars` sets the variable values similarly to how your JS example does, but without the `@`. This is where you're retrieve the values you want to populate with. In my case they were just calls to `get_theme_mod()`, but in yours you'd be using `WPEdenThemeEngine`. Doesn't really matter.

Next this is to create a hook that will save the compiled CSS, so that I don't need to generate it on each page load. In my case I'm using values from the Customizer so I used `customize_save_after` and saved the result into a new theme mod, `css`.

```
function wpse_283711_save_customizer_css() {
    set_theme_mod( 'css', wpse_283711_get_customizer_css() );
}
add_action( 'customize_save_after', 'wpse_283711_save_customizer_css' );
```

Then I need to output the custom CSS in the `<head>` using [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/).

```
function wpse_283711_enqueue_customizer_css() {
    $css = '';

    if ( is_customize_preview() ) {
        $css = wpse_283711_get_customizer_css();
    } elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'css' ) ) {
        $css = get_theme_mod( 'css' );
    }

    wp_add_inline_style( 'stylesheet-handle', $css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_283711_enqueue_customizer_css', 11 );
```

This will load the value of `get_theme_mod( 'css' )`, my saved CSS, into the `<head>` of the site, but notice that I check `is_customize_preview()`. Since I'm using customizer values, I want the preview to update when I change values in the Customizer.

Since Customizer controls don't trigger `customize_save_after` when changed, I need to compile the CSS each time the page loads, so if `is_customize_preview()` is true, I just run `wpse_283711_get_customizer_css()` directly without saving the result. You won't want parse LESS every real page load, which is why I save to a theme mod, but it's necessary for previewing changes. If you're not using the Customizer, this probably isn't relevant to you.